# Impossible to connect to LocalHost ( PostgreSQL )

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I'm trying to connect to localhost using the postgres user and the password I created during the installation but nothing happened. I looked everywhere and nothing works. I already have reinstalled the software. I'm running windows 10 and on the latest version of postgresql.

Here is how I set up the connection

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local    all     postgres    trust
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Where are you trying to connect from? How are you trying to connect? *I looked everywhere and nothing works* has no value. What **specifically** have you tried that didn't work for you?

Comment: I'm entering the followinf informations in the add server menu : postgres, localhost,and my password and this is working on my mac but not on my PC

Comment: What is the **exact** error message you get?

Comment: bad answer - tried this ?  host    all             all             127.0.0.0/24              md5

Comment: @yoyani Which PostgreSQL version are you using?